# ARKit not working as expected, If the surface is plain, like a one-colored wall, it’s not detected

Tags: ios, arkit, object-detection, surface, plane

I am working on one application which has one functionality like user needs to show the paintings(in 2D images) on the surface with ARKit.

I have implemented it but it has some issues.

It works only for the surfaces that have distinguishable features — e.g. hanging photos, text or art. If the surface is plain, like a one-colored wall, or has only a few small features, it’s not detected. Which means that most of the walls are invisible to ARKit.

Need some solution for this. Any help would be appreciated.

{

```
    self.node.removeFromParentNode()
    node.eulerAngles.z = 0
    //node.scale = SCNVector3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

    self.viewAR.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    self.viewAR.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 250, height: 250)
    self.imageView.frame = self.viewAR.frame

    self.node.geometry = SCNPlane(width: 0.05, height: 0.05)

    if selectedIndexPath.row < 0 {
        self.imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    }
    else {
        self.imageView.layer.borderColor = colors[selectedIndexPath.row].cgColor
    }

    self.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 10.0

    self.viewAR.addSubview(self.imageView)
    if let resWidth = self.newWork?.getSetArtWidth, let resHeight = self.newWork?.getSetArtHeight {
        if resWidth > 0.0 && resHeight > 0.0 {
            self.viewAR.addSubview(self.lblDimension)
            self.lblDimension.backgroundColor = colors[selectedIndexPath.row]
            self.lblDimension.textColor = UIColor.white

            self.lblDimension.text = "Size = \(resWidth) mm * \(resHeight) mm"
        }
    }



    if aRImageList.count != 0 {

        if let imgUrl = aRImageList[imageIndex]  as? String {
            if let resUrl = URL(string: imgUrl){
                self.imageView.sd_setImage(with: resUrl, placeholderImage: LISTING_PLACEHOLDER , completed: { (image, error, disk, imageURL) in
                    if error == nil {

                        self.imageView.image = image

                        if let image = image {
                            self.setImageSize(image)
                        }
                        self.node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
                        self.node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = self.viewAR.asImage()
                    }
                })
            } else {
                self.imageView.image = LISTING_PLACEHOLDER
            }
        }
        else if let resImage = aRImageList[imageIndex]  as? UIImage {
            self.imageView.image = resImage
        }

        //self.imageView.image = aRImageList[imageIndex]
    }
    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = viewAR.asImage()//aRImageList[imageIndex]//viewToAdd


    if isHorizontal == true {

        //let resScale = node.scale
       // let resAngle = node.eulerAngles.z
        node.position = SCNVector3(hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x, hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y, hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
        //node.scale = resScale
        //node.eulerAngles.z = resAngle
        node.pivot = SCNMatrix4Rotate(node.pivot, Float.pi, 0, 1, 0)
        let constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target:sceneView.pointOfView)
        constraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
        node.constraints = [constraint]



    }
    else {

        node.constraints = nil
        node.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0,0,0)
        let resScale = node.scale
        //let resAngle = node.eulerAngles.z
        node.transform = SCNMatrix4(hitTestResult.anchor!.transform)
        node.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(node.eulerAngles.x + (-Float.pi / 2), node.eulerAngles.y, node.eulerAngles.z)
        node.position = SCNVector3(hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x, hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y, hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z + 0.07)
        node.scale = resScale
       // node.eulerAngles.z = resAngle
    }
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    planeNode.removeFromParentNode()
    for removeNode in self.planeNodes {
        removeNode.removeFromParentNode()
    }


}
```